# High CPU usage using Lauterbach T32 with Linux/Qt

Tags: linux, qt, linux-mint, lauterbach

I'm experiencing a very high CPU usage (~100%) using the Qt version of T32 on Linux, even when the program is waiting user interaction. The executable is t32marm-qt.

This does not happen when I use the standard Tcl-based t32marm executable.

A strace shows that the executable continuosly cycles on the

```
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)
```

syscall.

The Linux distribution is Mint 14 32-bit (derivation of Ubuntu 12.10).

Has anybody experienced this behavior ?

If so, is it a bug or just a wrong configuration ?

Comment: I think this should be a bug on T32... I don't think it has to do with the framework per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have been just confirmed that it is a software bug, fixed in more recent versions of the tool. If you encounter such a problem, update your version.